# Audio resampling bug

Tags: c, audio, signal-processing, resampling

I'm trying to construct and use a basic audio resampler, taking WAVE file as input, resampling it to defined fs and returning resampled file. The code runs, but it generates inaudible output file that cannot be opened by Windows Media Player. I honestly don't know what causes this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "wavfile.h"

#define FRAME_SIZE 256


void resample(float *in, float *out, int inputFrameSize, int outputFrameSize, float inputFs, float outputFs, float *index, float firstsampleofthenextframe)
{
    float increment = inputFs/outputFs;
    int i;
    float frac;
    int intp;

for (i=0;i<outputFrameSize;i++)
{
    if ((*index) < inputFrameSize - 1) {
        //linear interpolation
        intp = (int)(*index);
        frac = (*index) - (float)intp;

        out[i] = frac * in[intp+1] + (1.0-frac) * in[intp];

    } else { //index between inputFrameSize-2 and inputFrameSize-1
        intp = (int)(*index);
        frac = (*index) - (float)intp;

        out[i] = frac * firstsampleofthenextframe + (1.0-frac) * in[intp];
      }
    //left_out[i] = 0.2*sin(0.001*3.141592635*(*index));
    (*index) += increment;
}

}

int main()
{
    struct wavfile_header readh;
    struct wavfile_header writeh;
    float left_in[FRAME_SIZE];
    float right_in[FRAME_SIZE];
    float left_out[FRAME_SIZE*2];
    float right_out[FRAME_SIZE*2];

//float *left_out;
//float *right_out;
float indexL, indexR; //sample index used for interpolation

FILE * infile;
FILE * outfile;
fpos_t position;

int numBytes, numFrames;
int i;
int outFrameSize;

readh.num_channels = 2;
readh.sample_rate = 44100;

writeh.num_channels = 2;
writeh.sample_rate = 48000;


outFrameSize = (int)((float)FRAME_SIZE * (float)(writeh.sample_rate) / (float)(readh.sample_rate));
//left_out = (float*) malloc(sizeof(float)*outFrameSize);
//right_out = (float*) malloc(sizeof(float)*outFrameSize);

infile = wavfile_open_read("input.wav", &readh);
if(!infile) {
    printf("read error");
    return 1;
}
outfile = wavfile_open_write("output.wav", &writeh); 
if(!outfile) {
    printf("write error");
    return 1;
}


//main processing loop
numBytes = readh.riff_length;
numFrames = numBytes / (2*FRAME_SIZE);

indexL = indexR = 0.f; //start from the 0th sample of the input signal

while(numFrames > 0)
{
    float left_overlap, right_overlap;
    short sl, sr;

    for(i=0;i<FRAME_SIZE;i++) //read frame
    {
        short sleft, sright;
        fread(&sleft ,sizeof(short),1, infile); //deinterleave samples
        fread(&sright ,sizeof(short),1, infile);
        fflush(infile);
        left_in[i] = sleft * 0.0000305185f; // * (1/32767) - 16-bit input automatically normalized to (-1, 1)
        right_in[i] = sright * 0.0000305185f; // * (1/32767) - 16-bit input automatically normalized to (-1, 1)
        numBytes -= 4;
    }
    fgetpos (infile, &position);

    //one sample ahead is needed to interpolate
    fread(&sl ,sizeof(short),1, infile); //deinterleave samples [warning: bug if the input file length is an exact number of frames]
    fread(&sr ,sizeof(short),1, infile);
    left_overlap = sl * 0.0000305185f; // * (1/32767) - 16-bit input automatically normalized to (-1, 1)
    right_overlap = sr * 0.0000305185f; // * (1/32767) - 16-bit input automatically normalized to (-1, 1)
    fsetpos (infile, &position);

    resample(left_in, left_out, FRAME_SIZE, outFrameSize, 44100, 48000, &indexL, left_overlap);
    resample(right_in, right_out, FRAME_SIZE, outFrameSize, 44100, 48000, &indexR, right_overlap);
    indexL -= (int)indexL;
    indexR -= (int)indexR;

    for(i=0;i<outFrameSize;i++) //read frame
    {
        short left, right;

        //left_out[i] = 0.5;
        //right_out[i] = 0.5;

        left = (short)(left_out[i] * 32767.f);
        right = (short)(right_out[i] * 32767.f);

        fwrite(&left ,sizeof(short),1, outfile); //deinterleave samples
        fwrite(&right ,sizeof(short),1, outfile);
        numBytes -= 4;
    }
    fflush(outfile);

    numFrames--;
}

/*
while(numBytes > 0)
{
    //below: temp
    short left, right;

    //left_out[i] = 0.5;
    //right_out[i] = 0.5;

    left = left_out[i] * 32767;
    right = right_out[i] * 32767;

    fwrite(&left ,sizeof(short),1, outfile); //deinterleave samples
    fwrite(&right ,sizeof(short),1, outfile);
    numBytes--;
}
*/

fflush(outfile);
//free(left_out);
//free(right_out);
fclose(outfile);
fclose(infile);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: The line:   numFrames = numBytes / (2*FRAME_SIZE); should be: .... /sizeof(short)* channels * FRAMESIZE otherwise it will try to make a file of to large size. making a resampling from 44100 results in remainder in the ratio. If the conversion is done from a file with a rate of 24000 it work.

Comment: using a frame size that is a common denominator helps (2352 for conversion between 44100 and 48000).

Comment: If Windows Media Player does not play the resulting file, it makes sense to look at the file with a hex editor and compare it to what's required by the WAVE file format ((see http://soundfile.sapp.org/doc/WaveFormat/)). E.g. I cannot see in your code where you set any chunksizes. Apparently you use some `wavefile` library. Which one is this? Where is it documented?